# Android spinner not select anything at launch

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I basically want the spinner to appear when the user checks the checkbox (it works). And the spinner has items for the user to pick but I know that spinner selects the first item automatically when launched.

[image]

-- Issue -- : whenever I check the checkbox and spinner appears, I can press the first item BUT the spinner does not GO AWAY and I can't get the String text of the selected item (as I use it to set the text of the CheckBox). I can only selected the items after the first one and then, WHEN: I check and uncheck the box I can only select other options and not the same one when selected before.

-- Goal -- : to be able to select the first item when checkbox appears if user selects it, and set the String text onto the Checkbox AND be able to select the same item even after the user unchecks and checks the checkbox.

Code for both checkbox and spinner:

```
 //checkbox
        giftwrapchecker = findViewById(R.id.checker);
        notEligible();
        giftwrapchecker.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b==false){giftwrapoptions.setVisibility(View.GONE); pricetagTv.setText("RM " + (bottles * perbottle)); giftwrapchecker.setText(R.string.giftq);}
                else {giftwrapoptions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);setGiftprice();}
            }
        });

        //spinner to check if the user has interacted with the spinner yet
        giftwrapoptions.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                isTouched = true;
                return false;
            }
        });


        //getting user selection and removes spinner once user has chosen and also set the chosen item's text onto the checkbox

        giftwrapoptions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            //this is the first item that the spinner auto selects
            String preselecteditem = giftwrapoptions.getSelectedItem().toString();
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (isTouched) {
                    //this is the item that user has selected
                    String item =  giftwrapoptions.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    System.out.println("Selected "+item);
                    giftwrapchecker.setText(item);
                    giftwrapoptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if (item==preselecteditem){
                        giftwrapchecker.setText(preselecteditem);
                        giftwrapoptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);}

                    }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {}
        });

    }

    private int getSum() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i< qty.size();i++){
            sum += (Integer.parseInt(qty.get(i)));
        }
        return sum;
    }
  
    private void notEligible(){
        if (bottles==3 || bottles==6 || bottles==12){
            giftwrapchecker.setEnabled(true);
            giftwrapoptions.setEnabled(true);
           
        } else{
            giftwrapchecker.setChecked(false);
            giftwrapchecker.setEnabled(false);
            giftwrapchecker.setText(R.string.giftna);
            giftwrapoptions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            giftwrapoptions.setEnabled(false);
        }
        pricetagTv.setText("RM " + (bottles * perbottle));
    }
```

Comment: ran into this prob once. my suggestion is if it is not absolutely necessary to use spinner) use <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ...>
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">
        
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
     
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout> however, if you strictly want spinner than I will provide in a while

Comment: and implement drop down with the text view?

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but wouldn't it be easier on you and and your app's users to leave the spinner shown? What if the user wants to change their selection? What if they don't realize that they have to click in the spinner even if the default option it shows is the one they want? If you really want it this way, you could add a "Select an item..." entry as the first entry (default) in the spinner to help with both problems.

Comment: yes implement drop down with the textview (works same as spinner but gives you "Select an item" option in easy way as in spinner "select" entry will also be added to list)...but if you want Spinner way -> create custom spinner with background (google and see ans in SO) 2) in code stop it loading the default first item (search on SO you will find spinner class for the same) than use spinner as required